# Present View Controller not working with ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentviewcontroller

Present view controller is not working with ios 9,
when I press the button it not redirected to present view controller.

Why this happens ?

> I had tried the below code

```
 RegistrationViewController * viewController =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Registration" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegistrationViewController"];
 [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

> I had also tried the below code

```
 UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Registration"
                                                         bundle:nil];
 RegistrationViewController *add =
 [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegistrationViewController"];
 [self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self presentViewController:add
                               animated:YES
                             completion:nil];
        });
  }];
```

**Edit**

> My complete code here. I am using Xcode 7 and running it with ios 9

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "RegistrationViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)actionRegistrationClicked:(id)sender
{
    RegistrationViewController * viewController =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Registration" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegistrationViewController"];
     [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
@end
```

> Registration view controller

```
#import "RegistrationViewController.h"

@interface RegistrationViewController ()

@end

@implementation RegistrationViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: yes, you can see the code, I had written in my question

Comment: Check if `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier]` returns the view controller instance,.

Comment: Why you present two time?

Comment: I had just tried both the code but not working, I am not presenting two time

Comment: Yes, Its returns the instance @ProblemSlover

Comment: Alright. If it returns the controller instance . check if method `viewDidLoad`  is called inside `RegistrationViewController`

Comment: No, its not calling. Application stops when I click on button and every control becomes disable.

Comment: check if and you binded a button to a single action method
eg. -(void)buttonDidClickAction

Comment: Have you set the "Storyboard ID" property? Also as @ProblemSlover suggested, ensure that it RegistrationViewController is not nil. Add an NSLog statement after this line `RegistrationViewController * viewController =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Registration" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegistrationViewController"];`

Comment: do u have storyboard ID with name RegistrationViewController ?

Comment: Will u give a try by declare the view controller as a member or property of the presenting view controller`s class ?

Comment: yes, I have with same name which I had defined in code

Comment: I am not getting your point @RatulSharker. brief it.

Comment: where r u calling this code ?

Comment: on button's action @Mr.T

Comment: Declare a property of registration view controller in your current view controller class, then instantiate it, and then present it as above

Comment: what is your current view controller ? Can you do po self in the debugger by setting a break point in the button method

Comment: Where are you calling presentViewController? in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Make sure you binded a button to a single action method

Comment: Do you check instance add? it show frame or something?

Comment: YEs, I had bind it with single method

Comment: @RatulSharker still not working

Comment: @Florence Can you put your complete code into pastebin.?

Comment: I wondered y it isnt working.do u want to team view or send the source code :P @Florence

Comment: I had updated the question. please look into it

Comment: is the action touch up inside ?

Comment: are you sure that  `actionRegistrationClicked` is called ? i doubt the `IBaction` attached correctly, will you please place a `NSLog` inside the `actionRegistrationClicked`.

Comment: @Florence I doubt that controller is being initialized . Please make sure again setting debug point inside your action method that view controller instance is initialized and it's an instance of RegistrationViewController by casting to view controller as follows: 
`(RegistrationViewController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@....`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure the presentedViewController is nil. If presentedViewController is not nil change the code to following.

```
RegistrationViewController * viewController =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Registration" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegistrationViewController"];

if ([self presentedViewController]) {
    [[self presentedViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
    }];
} else {
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: did you get any warning while presenting the viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

try viewDidAppear in

```
  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 
         [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Always call super in such methods.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code:

```
RegistrationViewController * viewController = [[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegistrationViewController"];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I think you are presenting the same viewController you are already in.

Comment: no way, I am in login view controller and I am gonna to present registration  view controller.

Comment: Its not necessary that login & registration view controller to be in same storybaord.@balaji