# IOS passing var w/ latitude & longitude with type-cast to CLLocationCoordinate2D shows different maps locations

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have this weird issue when passing values to CLLocationCoordinate2D from a variable. 
But if I use the same values hardcoded. Then it works perfectly.

I am fetching the values from this page.
http://localsearch.azurewebsites.net/api/Locations

store it on a NSMutable array as Dicts.
All the values get store and get retrieved with no issue.
I am fetching everything as strings and then Type casting them to whatever is necessary. which in this case it would be lat and long to doubles or floats ( I have try both ended up in the same result ).

I print the values before they get place on the CL CLLocationCoordinate2D. and they are fine. Same values as in the hardcoded ones. I have taken some screenshots and hopes that may be someone has come across this issue.

This screenshot is to show the value that my coord var gets from a the hardcoded values above.
[image: This is the one showing the hardcoded values]

Now, this screenshot shows the value that my coord2 var gets from the variables that store the same values that where previously pass hardcoded.
In the bottom you can see NSLog prints the same values. But for some reason they do get different values.

[image: This is the one showing with the passed values.]

So obviously, having the wrong lat and long the results in the map is that I end up swiming in the ocean.
[image: location by passed var]

Thanks for the help.
PS: let me know if you guys need me to add code snips of what I have done. Not sure if its needed as this is the specific place where the values just don't match.

this is my tableview code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //Fetching data from API URL
    NSURL *locationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:JSON_URL];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:locationURL];
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *locationsDictionary in dataDictionary){
        LocationObjects *currentLocation = [[LocationObjects alloc] initWithId:[locationsDictionary objectForKey:@"ID"]
                                                                          Name:[locationsDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"]
                                                                      Latitude:[locationsDictionary objectForKey:@"Latitude"]
                                                                     Longitude:[locationsDictionary objectForKey:@"Longitude"]
                                                                       Address:[locationsDictionary objectForKey:@"Address"]
                                                                   ArrivalTime:[locationsDictionary objectForKey:@"ArrivalTime"]];

        [self.objectHolderArray addObject:currentLocation];
    }
    //[objectHolderSortedArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[self sortArray]];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    UIBarButtonItem *btn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                         target:self
                                                         action:@selector(dismissView)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btn;


}
-(NSMutableArray *)objectHolderArray{
    if(!objectHolderArray) objectHolderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return objectHolderArray;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //NSLog(@"returns the count in the array: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.objectHolderArray count]);
    return [self.objectHolderArray count];
}
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        LocationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[LocationTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        }


        LocationObjects *currentLocation = [self.objectHolderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.lblId.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",currentLocation.Id];
        cell.lblcurrentName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@",currentLocation.Name];
        cell.lblgivenAddress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Address: %@",currentLocation.Address];


        return cell;
    }

    #pragma mark - Table View Delegate
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        LocationObjects *currentLocation = [self.objectHolderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %lu", indexPath.row);
        if(!LocationMapVC) LocationMapVC = [[LocationMapViewController alloc] init];
        LocationMapVC.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@",currentLocation.Name];
        //NSLog(@"Name: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@",currentLocation.Name]);
        LocationMapVC.address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Address: %@",currentLocation.Address];



        LocationMapVC.latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude: %@",currentLocation.Latitude];
        NSLog(@"Latitude: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude: %@",currentLocation.Latitude]);

        LocationMapVC.longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Longitude: %@",currentLocation.Longitude];
        NSLog(@"Longitude: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Longitude: %@",currentLocation.Longitude]);

        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758859/present-view-controller-not-working-with-ios-9
        [self presentViewController:LocationMapVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        LocationMapVC = nil;
    }
```

and this is my mapview code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //late instantiation
    if (!mapView) {
        mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    }

    //dismiss modal button
    UIButton *done = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [done addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [done setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    done.frame = CGRectMake(((self.view.frame.size.width)/2)+10, (self.view.frame.size.height)-60, 160, 40);
    done.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    //direction modal button
    UIButton *directions = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [directions addTarget:self action:@selector(showRouteVC) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [directions setTitle:@"Route" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    directions.frame = CGRectMake(((self.view.frame.size.width)/2)-170, (self.view.frame.size.height)-60, 160, 40);
    directions.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    //Location Manager
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    //[locationManager requestLocation];
    //[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    //mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;

    //MAPING VALUES
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude =  41.883976, .longitude =  -87.639346};
    NSLog(@"In location map the Latitude: %@ and Longitutude: %@", latitude, longitude);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2 = {.latitude = [latitude doubleValue],.longitude = [longitude doubleValue]};

    MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.03, .longitudeDelta =  0.03};

    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};


    //implementing annotations base of the info passed.
    annotation = [[Annotation alloc] initWithAnnotation:coord title:name subtitle:address];


    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    //adding subviews.
    [mapView setRegion:region];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    [self.view addSubview:done];
    [self.view addSubview:directions];
}
```

Comment: Its all in the original question.  down vote
favorite
I have this weird issue when passing values to CLLocationCoordinate2D from a variable. But if I use the same values hardcoded. Then it works perfectly.

I am fetching the values from this page. http://localsearch.azurewebsites.net/api/Locations
store the values on a NSMutable array as Dicts. All the values get store and get retrieved with no issue. According to what I been reading and doing research you have to pass a double to CLLocationCoordinate2D which is why I am type-casting to a double.

Comment: fetching the data and storing in it as a dictionary on an NSMutable Array. I recall the data based on the click on the IndexPath.row. Pass the value to the map VC and then typecast it as a double value. If I hard code the values. I get the location. If I pass the variables then I end up somewhere in the ocean.

Comment: Look. There is just one line of interest, this one: `CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2 = {.latitude = [latitude doubleValue],.longitude = [longitude doubleValue]};` That value is coming out, we now know, as `{0,0}`. So now we need to know: what is `latitude`, such as that `[latitude doubleValue]` is `0`? And the answer is: anything that can't be readily converted to a double. So you need to work out precisely what `latitude` _is_. And when you know, you'll know why this is happening. Do you see?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I was able to figure out thanks to [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) and some other helping hands.

the mistake I was making is here.

```
    LocationMapVC.latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude: %@",currentLocation.Latitude];
    LocationMapVC.longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Longitude: %@",currentLocation.Longitude];
```

I was passing stringWithFormat and adding the "Latitude: " and "Longitude: " to the strings. Obviously at the other end this can not be turned into double, which was returning the 0,0. So to fix it. All that needed to be done was pass the value without the stringWithFormat. That looks like this.

```
    LocationMapVC.latitude = currentLocation.Latitude;
    LocationMapVC.longitude = currentLocation.Longitude;
```

and that was the end of it. Thank you matt for hinting where to look into to solve this. Hope this help someone in the future.